# Listen for function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using a third party script that I don't want to modify.

In this script, there is a function that I need to listen for that adds a class to a dom node.

```
  function _showElement(targetElement) {
      targetElement.element.className += 'this-class';
  }
```

What I would like to do is listen for this element to be called and whenever it does add a class to its parent with pure javascript.

```
function addThis() {
    var doc = document;
    liveEl = doc.getElementsByName("this-class");
    // Code to add class to parent
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest "brute force" solution is to hijack (redefine) the function:

```
function _showElement(targetElement) {
  console.log('original');
}

_showElement(); // hijacked


function _showElement(targetElement) {
  console.log('hijacked');
}
```

Unfortunately i don't think you can save the original behavior of the function, so you need to copy-paste it:

```
function _showElement(targetElement) {
  targetElement.element.className += 'this-class';
  addThis()
}
```

---

Another solution, more specific to your problem (do something when the className of an element changes) you can listen for mutation events on the DOM:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Basically you create a MutationObserver and observe attribute changes on your element. It might not be such a great solution if you need to track all the nodes, but in some cases it might come in handy.

Comment: You can definitely save the original as well and then just invoke it in the modified function. http://jsfiddle.net/LordDaimos/2Ma72/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly. You can't listen event like dom attribute change. However, there is a way that you can identify the event which is trigger `_showElement` and attach a one more handler to the event which should call `addThis` function.